# Alamofire post request with params in the URL in swift

Tags: swift, post, parameters, alamofire

I have a post method with base url and various parameters appended in the base url itself.
The code is given below:

```
 let todosEndpoint:String =  "https://xxxxxxx/api/post_schedule_form_data?service_type=nanny&start_date=07/20/2020&start_time=06:00&end_date=07/20/2020&end_time=09:00&work_description=Work Description&special_instructions=Special Instructions&location_address=location_address&postal_code=abc123&current_profile_id=10"

 let header: HTTPHeaders = ["Content-Type":"application/json","x-token":self.usertoken!]
           
           print("the url is",todosEndpoint)

        AF.request(todosEndpoint, method: .post, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: header)
               .responseJSON { response in
                switch response.result {
                               case .success(let json):
                                   print("Validation Successful",json)
                    case let .failure(error):
                                       print(error)
                                   }
                    }
```

I do not get any response in the code.What could the error be?

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you've got a number of illegal characters in your query params (e.g. ":", "/", " ").

I suggest you build your URL using URLComponents. Pass in the endpoint and the query params and then get back the path. That will show you what needs to be escaped.

### Edit:

I guess I was wrong about ":" and "/". It looks like those are legal as part of a query param value.

This code:

```
var components = URLComponents()
components.scheme = "https"
components.host = "xxxxxxx"
components.path = "/api/post_schedule_form_data"
components.queryItems = [
    URLQueryItem(name: "service_type", value: "nanny"),
    URLQueryItem(name: "start_date", value: "07/20/2020"),
    URLQueryItem(name: "start_time", value: "06:00"),
    URLQueryItem(name: "end_date", value: "07/20/2020"),
    URLQueryItem(name: "end_time", value: "09:00"),
    URLQueryItem(name: "work_description", value: "Work Description"),
    URLQueryItem(name: "special_instructions", value: "Special Instructions"),
    URLQueryItem(name: "location_address", value: "location_address"),
    URLQueryItem(name: "postal_code", value: "abc123"),
    URLQueryItem(name: "current_profile_id", value: "10"),
]

print(components.string ?? "nil")
```

Outputs the string

```
https://xxxxxxx/api/post_schedule_form_data?service_type=nanny&start_date=07/20/2020&start_time=06:00&end_date=07/20/2020&end_time=09:00&work_description=Work%20Description&special_instructions=Special%20Instructions&location_address=location_address&postal_code=abc123&current_profile_id=10
```

Note that the spaces get escaped as `%20`.

That is probably the only illegal part of your URL string.

`URLComponents` is your friend because it applies escaping to the different parts of the URL as needed, and enforces the correct escaping rules for each of the different parts of the URL.

### Edit #2:

This code:

```
let urlString: String =  "https://xxxxxxx/api/post_schedule_form_data?service_type=nanny&start_date=07/20/2020&start_time=06:00&end_date=07/20/2020&end_time=09:00&work_description=Work Description&special_instructions=Special Instructions&location_address=location_address&postal_code=abc123&current_profile_id=10"

let componentsFromString = URLComponents(string: urlString)

print(componentsFromString?.string ?? "nil" )
```

displays "nil"

That tells you there is something illegal about your URL string.

Comment: I tried this method and of it is printing the url correctly,but i missed out few more parameters and those are not printed properly in this fomat.Those parameters are childrens[0][age] = 0to4,childrens[0][total]=3,childrens[0][special_assistance]=No,special_category[]=bath..As you can see,there are many square brackets or array in this case,when i use similar style,i get the output string as service_category%5B%5D=bath for service_category[]=bath.How to handle this array?

Comment: Using the URLComponents code I posted lets you figure out (and generate) the escaping needed for each part of a URL. Given that it escapes your square brackets, that tells you those characters are illegal in query parameters. If you pass the query parameters in escaped form, they should be unescaped on the server before you attempt to parse them, so the conversion from `[` to `%5B` and `]` to `%5D` should be fine.

Comment: So it has to be replaced in unescaped format before passing it to the server?

Comment: No. You send the URL in escaped format. It gets un-escaped on the server.

Comment: Use the code in my answer to build your URL. That will escape the different parts as needed to make them legal, and the server should un-escape the URL before parsing it.

Comment: You mean the backend they should un-escape it?

Comment: Yes, the back-end should un-escape the URL before parsing it. That's how URL escaping works.

Answer (score 0):

Your headers are not going through correctly...
Also, you're passing " " (spaces) in your URL, just replace them with "%20".
The correct way to do this would be:

```
let url:String =  "https://xxxxxxx/api/post_schedule_form_data?service_type=nanny&start_date=07/20/2020&start_time=06:00&end_date=07/20/2020&end_time=09:00&work_description=Work Description&special_instructions=Special Instructions&location_address=location_address&postal_code=abc123&current_profile_id=10".replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "%20")

var request = URLRequest(url:  NSURL(string: url)! as URL)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.setValue(self.usertoken!, forHTTPHeaderField: "x-token")
AF.request(request).responseJSON { response in
     switch response.result {
            case .success(let json):
                 print("Validation Successful",json)
            case let .failure(error):
                  print(error)
      }
}
```

You are force unwrapping self.usertoken, so beware of that as well!
Also seems like the date in the URL has "/" which you must change to "%2F" in the URL or better the format in the backend!

Comment: I tried this method and i got Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value: in the line  var request = URLRequest(url:  NSURL(string: url)! as URL)

Comment: Yes. The String couldn’t be converted to a URL because it has special characters like “/“ in the parameters, replace them with “%2F”.

Comment: https://xxxxxxx/api/post_schedule_form_data?service_type=nanny&start_date=07%2F20%2F2020&start_time=06:00&end_date=07%2F20%2F2020&end_time=09:00&childrens[0][age]=0to4&childrens[0][total]=3&childrens[0][special_assistance]=No&service_category[]=bath&frequency_type=onetime&number_nannies=1&work_description=Work Description&special_instructions=Special Instructions&location_address=location_address&postal_code=abc123&zero_to_four=20.00&four_above=17.50&tax_hst=0.13&transport_charge=10&current_profile_id=10..This is the url string after replacing / with %2F...